# Flask serve self-contained static project

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have several already complete, self-contained static projects that I'd like to serve with Flask. My project directory looks something like:

```
- flask
  - flaskr.py
  - projects
    - project1
      - index.html
      - css.css
      - js.js
    - project2
      - ...
    - ...
```

I've tried to just `send_static_file` my `index.html`:

```
@app.route('/proj1')
def proj1():
  return app.send_static_file("projects/index.html")
```

However, its references to `css.css` and `js.js` then point to `/css.css` and `/js.js` instead of `/projects/project1/css.css` and `/projects/project1/js.js`.

I've also tried to modify `app.root_path` before calling `send_static_file`, and then resetting it afterwards, but that always results in a 404.

Inserting a `<base href="/projects/project1/">` tag right after the `<head>` seems to work, but feels hacky to me. I'd like to find a more "correct" solution.

How can I achieve this? I do not want to modify *any* code in the projects; it should be as drag-and-droppable as possible.

Comment: Why do you use flask for that and not a webserver like apache or nginx? (It doesn't really alter anything, I'm just curious.)

Comment: @syntonym I'm familiar with Flask, so it's my goto for any web hosting. Also, this behavior is only part of the project; there will also be more "flask-esque" stuff.

Comment: I'm sure you have seen it but in the case you have not (or for others reading your question that didn't see it) [flask recommends not running the development server in production](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/#deployment). Good luck with your project!

Comment: @Quelklef I am not just curious. I will make a very forceful declaration: using a dynamic web application engine to serve a completely static site is incompetent. Learn your web server (Nginx, IIS). You should already be a little bit familiar with one since your existing Flask apps should be behind one in prod. Flask *does* have a mechanism for [serving static files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/static/), but you 1. should prefer to let the web server bypass Flask for this route in prod, and 2. only use it for resource files required by the dynamic app (e.g., CSS, JS, images).

Comment: I will note there's at least one use case for having a dynamic application serve static files: when you need access control over them. But in this case, the endpoint is actually dynamic, despite the *content* being static. The endpoint has to access a user store, allow users to log in/out, and check the privileges of the user every time a request is made.

Comment: And yes, that's all very harsh. But that is the reality of how you'll be perceived as a professional if you do this, and there's good reasons for that perception. Flask is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: @jpmc26 I value what you've said (though I don't understand 100% of it; I'm not a professional web dev) and since it applies to _my_ situation, I will look into nginx. However, I'd like to note that there is the case of the "whole"/"parent" site being dynamic but still wanting to statically server the "children sites"/submodules. Though I suppose something more heavyweight than Flask would be in order in that situation?

Comment: @Quelklef The normal way of doing that is still via the overarching web server. They can be configured to route requests differently based on the path. So yes, you can have Nginx send requests root URL (e.g., `https://www.example.com`) requests through Flask and still have it serve the static subpath (e.g. `https://www.example.com/my/static/stuff`) without invoking Flask. The configuration is a bit more complex, but it's normal. Part of what I was saying above is that in production, it's normal to do that even for Flask's built in `static` (e.g., `https://www.example.com/static` path.

Comment: @jpmc26 I did not know this. Thank you so much! If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jpmc26 states, the question is wrong from the get-go. Flask should be used for a dynamic site and is both overkill and not suited for this use-case. Instead, usage of a web server like Nginx is recommended. If dynamic content ever is desired, Nginx will be able to route requests to a child Flask server.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `send_static_file` only sends a static file, it does no rewriting or anything. So the file arrives at the client as it is on the filesystem.

The browser GETs `/proj1` and gets an HTML file that says "Also download `css.css` and add it to this document". The browser doesn't know that the HTML file originally resides at `/projects/project1/index.html`, it only knows it accessed `/proj1`. So it looks for the `css.css` file relative to the file it accessed, so it looks for `/css.css`.

If you serve the `index.html` via `/projects/project1/index.html` (or any other path that resides in `/projects/project1/`) the relative lookup will lead to `/projects/project1/css.css`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I will wait a little while to see if another more flexible solution comes along and, if not, accept your answer.

Comment: You could "manually" read the `index.html` file and replace any links to point to `/projects/projectX`, but to me that would feel somewhat hacky. It might still be a good solution in your context.

Comment: I guess you could also readout the `Referer` header and answer with the appropriate css/js. Feels even more hacky, but again, if it works it works.

Comment: I'm not sure how that `Referer` sol'n would work, but my current way is via a programmatically inserted `<base>` tag which is similar to replacing the links in `index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

In [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561089/4420934) I outlined why this problem happens and suggested a solution so that the browser can infer the correct position of the ressource. Another possibility is for flask to figure out what ressource the browser actually wanted. "Normally" the browser sends the [referer header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) with a request (there are exceptions though) and we can use this to deduce which `css.css` was meant:

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/css.css')
def css():
    r = request.referrer
    if r.endswith("proj1"):
        app.send_static_file("projects/project1/css.css")
```

This is pretty hacky and personally I would not recommend it, essentially you either have to hardcode the projects or implement some registering to automate that.